# Vuepress - Components customized

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuepress

I'm new in Vuepress. I want to make a blog with a Vuepress-theme is available from github:

https://github.com/vuepress/vuepress-theme-blog

The official documentation shows how to change some things, for example the header, footer... as a colours, links... here more info:

https://vuepress-theme-blog.ulivz.com/config/#nav

To custom the allow parameters is from the file config.js with from module.exports object:

```
module.exports = {
  themeConfig: {
    nav: [
      {
        text: 'Blog',
        link: '/',
      },
      {
        text: 'Tags',
        link: '/tag/',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

But I would like to change the full navbar component. For this only I have found the way inside:

```
/node_modules/@vuepress-themeblog/components/Header.vue
```

At summary I want to know the best way to create new components. Maybe it's the better option change directly inside the components folder of the theme or is there any way?

I'm very confused in the documentation only shows a little changes.

Please Could you give me some advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't edit the code inside the `node_modules` dir, as it is third-party code managed by the package manager.
You can solve your problem by creating your own theme using the vuepress-themeblog as a starting point.

The steps to write custom themes are described in the [documentation](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/writing-a-theme.html). Copy the content of the [vuepress-theme-blog repository](https://github.com/vuepress/vuepress-theme-blog) into your `theme` folder and start working on your custom components.